# Why doesn't a .ts file play?

Tags: html, video, type-conversion, video-streaming, video-player

I'm trying to download a video from this URL: https://world-vod.dchdns.net/hlss/dch/218-1/,h264_LOW_THREE,h264_LOW_TWO,h264_LOW_ONE,h264_MEDIUM_TWO,h264_MEDIUM_ONE,h264_HIGH,h264_VERY_HIGH_ONE,.mp4.urlset/seg-54-f7-v1-a1.ts

I can download the file but no videoplayer can play it. Is it encrypted? Is there any option to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is encrypted. You can't "fix" it unless you know the decryption key.